# confused about printf() that contains prefix and postfix operators

Tags: c, programming-languages

If int var=20 then how

```
printf("%d %d %d", var--, ++var, --var);
```

execution happens in C programming language.

Comment: There are quite a few very similar questions about undefined behaviour on SO already, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902638/post-and-pre-increment-in-c and many more...

Answer (score 8):

It is undefined behaviour because `var` is modified several times without a sequence point in between. A sequence point would be, for example, a `;`. The commas in parameter lists, do, however, not introduce sequence points, also the order in which the operands are evaluated is undefined (you could say, the code is doubly undefined ...).

Comment: The order in which the operands are evaluated is not undefined, it is unspecified (there is an evaluation order, the implementation just doesn't have to document it nor to be consistent -- even between two executions of the same code line).

Comment: You might want to consider the sequence of function parameter is being processed.