# printf using stack?

Tags: c++, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [confused about printf() that contains prefix and postfix operators.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109475/confused-about-printf-that-contains-prefix-and-postfix-operators)

I came across a code with the following snippet,

```
int main()  {
    int c = 100;
    printf("\n %d \t %d \n", c, c++);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 100 & 101 but I get output as

```
 101     100
```

Could anyone help me know why?

Comment: I guess the code is evaluating the printf parameters in reverse order, thus the c from "c++" parameter is inserted first, then the previous c parameter is inserted, which is then already incremented.

If you want to do 1 plus c for the second value, and increment c too, I guess you'll have to use printf("\n %d \t %d\n", c, c+1 ); c++;

Answer (score 9):

The C and C++ standards do not guarantee the order of evaluation of function parameters. Most compilers will evaluate parameters from right to left because that is the order they get pushed on the stack using the cdecl calling convention.

Comment: Man! You have to be dang quick here on answering these "why does my program do <this>" type questions when <this> is undefined behavior.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf it is not undefined

Comment: @ashmish2: The `<this>` in David Hammens comment is not `printf` (which is a well-defined function) but the `c, c++` arguments. That's undefined. See the previous Q on this topic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109475/confused-about-printf-that-contains-prefix-and-postfix-operators

Comment: @asmish2: The problem isn't printf. Calling `any_function_whatsoever (c, c++)` results in undefined behavior because those commas are not sequence points. It is illegal (undefined behavior) to modify and access the same value in one sequence.

Answer (score 5):

There is no guarantee  whether `c` on the left, or `c++` on the right, will be evaluated  first.

The order of evaluation of function parameters is **Unspecifeid** and hence **Undefined Behavior** as per the standard.

As per ***Section 1.9 of the C++ standard***:

*"Certain other aspects and operations of the abstract machine are described in this International Standard as `unspecified` (`for example, order of evaluation of arguments to a function`). Where possible, this International Standard defines a set of allowable behaviors. These define the nondeterministic aspects of the abstract machine."*

Comment: You have a big bold "Unspecified Behavior" in your question. But that's not so useful, because as a consequence the behavior is undefined. So you should have at least a bigger bolder "Undefined behavior" in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you had just used `printf ("%d\n", c++)` or `printf ("%d\n", c)` the result would have been 100 in either case. Printing both c and c++ in one function call as you did is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score -3):

printf works from right to left so first c++ is executed (c= 100) then after C++ executes and C=101 
therefore 101 and 100 is output
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf

Comment: -1. This is wrong. There can be no expectation of what the result of invoking undefined behavior is.

Comment: its not undefinef http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf read wiki atleast.. by default printf is right aligned

Comment: @ashmish2: you're confusing how printf processes its arguments, and how the arguments are "prepared" at the call site before they are handed to printf. That second part (order of evaluation of the arguments in a function call) is unspecified by the standard.